# PDO How to echo how many updated

Tags: php, pdo, rowcount

How can I echo how many records were updated with this code?
I know that I can do this in a common update:

```
echo $stmt->rowCount() . " records UPDATED successfully";
```

But the question here is, how to do it when there is multiple updates at the same time.

NOTE ABOUT POSSIBLE DUPLICATE: I already have explained that my question is different than: [PDO were rows affected during execute statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522520/pdo-were-rows-affected-during-execute-statement)
That solution is for a single update and it does not work in this code. What I ask is how to count when there is multiple updates.

```
try {
    require_once 'connexion.php';

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE bookmarks
                            SET podcast=:podcast, text=:text
                            WHERE id=:id");
    $stmt->bindParam(':podcast', $podcast);
    $stmt->bindParam(':text', $text);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);

    $podcast = 1;
    $text = "text 1";
    $id = 147;
    $stmt->execute();

    // another row:
    $podcast = 2;
    $text = "text 2";
    $id = 265;
    $stmt->execute();

    // echo " records UPDATED successfully";
}

catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: This is some funky code you've got going there. What are you trying to achieve with this script?

Comment: `$stmt -> rowCount()` The `rowCount()` function returns the number of affected rows

Comment: possible duplicate of [PDO were rows affected during execute statement](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10522520/pdo-were-rows-affected-during-execute-statement)

Comment: @Ben I do no understand your comment. What is wrong with the code? I try to update with prepared statements. I just adapted what I found in the php manual: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php I am very new, doing my first tutorial. Feel free to correct me. I want to learn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

As you are doing multiple `->execute()` you will have to capture the count of each `->execute()` as you do it and then show the accumulated total count at the end

```
try {
    require_once 'connexion.php';
    $update_count = 0;

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("UPDATE bookmarks
                            SET podcast=:podcast, text=:text
                            WHERE id=:id");
    $stmt->bindParam(':podcast', $podcast);
    $stmt->bindParam(':text', $text);
    $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);

    $podcast = 1;
    $text = "text 1";
    $id = 147;
    $stmt->execute();

    $update_count += $stmt->rowCount();


    // another row:
    $podcast = 2;
    $text = "text 2";
    $id = 265;
    $stmt->execute();

    $update_count += $stmt->rowCount();


    echo "$update_count records UPDATED successfully";
}

catch(PDOException $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: Really? Duplicate answer? :)

Comment: Well its slightly different as I assume he missed that he would have to capture the `->rowCount()` after each `->execute()` and not just once at the end of the `try block`

Comment: No you will get 1 for each update. it reports how many rows were updated when issueing the `->execute()` If you issue an update with the same criteria twice then the update will be run successfully both times. So each `->rowCount` will return 1

Comment: I assume you have just implified a loop that exists in your real code. If you dont want to count duplicate updates then you will have to cleanup your input data to remove duplicate `id`'s before using it in the loop

Answer (score 0):

Try `$stm->rowCount()`. Source here: http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

The question was already asked here as well: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10522575/2853903

Comment: If we are being pedantic - This really should have been a comment as it is not an answer to this specific question

Comment: True. Since I do not have the rating yet would you consider marking the question as a duplicate?

Comment: Well I dont actually consider it a duplicate as it is distinct enough from the other question/answer that you and I bothered to search for to make the answer require more detail than was given in the other answer.

Comment: I already tried your option before asking. This only works with a simple update. But with the prepare estatement and multiple updates, this does not work